# net use command - WinXP Embedded

Tags: dos, windows-xp-embedded

I'm trying to use the 'net use' command to map a drive from a Windows XP Embedded system(built using Target Designer), but when I try to execute the 'net use' command, it is un-recognized.  The command works great on my desktop WinXP machine, just not on the embedded system.  I'm not sure if we are missing a package that needs to be on the XP Embedded system?

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**  **Thanks!**

Here is how i'm using the net use command:

```
net use X: \\150.168.80.4\Shared_Test
```

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:  Map to a drive from a WinXP Embedded machine only if the file server (Windows XP) is available. The batch file listed below is the one being run on the WinXP Embedded system.

```
:VERIFY
echo.
echo ----------VERIFYING FILESERVER AVAILABILITY----------
ping 150.168.80.4 -n 2
if errorlevel 1 goto RETRY
if errorlevel 0 goto MAPDRIVE
goto END

:RETRY
    echo.
    echo ----------FILESERVER UNAVAILABLE.......RETRYING!----------
    goto VERIFY


:MAPDRIVE
    echo.
    echo ----------FILESERVER AVAILABLE.....TRYING TO MAP TO FILESERVER----------
    net use X: \\150.168.80.4\Shared_Test
    ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5 >NUL
    IF NOT EXIST M:\ goto MAPDRIVE
    IF EXIST M:\ goto END

:END
echo.
echo ----------FILESERVER MAPPING SUCCESSFUL....GOODBYE!----------
    echo.
```

Comment: I'm experiencing this issue, did you find any workaround?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably unrelated, but I see a problem you could be having--in the :MAPDRIVE section you are mapping the drive as letter **X:**, but then checking to see if drive letter **M:** is available... so even if X: mapped successfully, this batch script would loop forever until/unless you had an M:-drive.

As for XP-Embedded not having the 'net use' command, I dunno... In WinXP the net.exe command is found in "C:\Windows\System32\net.exe" by default. Can you check on your XP-Embedded has this executable? If so, do the commands `net /?` or `net use /?` give you syntax help?

Comment: The M: & X: was an oversight on my part when cutting/pasting here.....I will check for net.exe, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The net command is provided by a Windows Embedded component called "Net.exe Utility". Search for it in Target Designer and add it to your target.